# How to disable gem temporarily in Rails 3 using Bundler?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, character-encoding, rubygems, bundler, redgreen

I have discovered that the redgreen gem is incompatible with ISO-8859-1 encoding of test files. What is the best way to disable one gem temporarily to run certain test files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first advice would be to save those files in UTF-8.

Alternatively, I'd look into the [grouping feature](http://gembundler.com/groups.html) of Bundler.

In your `Gemfile`

```
group :utf8 do
  gem 'redgreen'
end
```

And then `require` that group only when you want to use the `redgreen` gem.

```
Bundler.require(:utf8, :default, Rails.env)
```